# c# OutOfMemoryException When I use a datatable to load data from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

I wrote this code:

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tablename", conn);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
datatable dt = new datatable();
dt.load(dr);
```

But I get an exception as shown below when I load data into the datatable because I have an xml column with a big size (102 MB).

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

I'm very grateful if someone can give me the solution for this exception.

Comment: Do you need the XML column?

Comment: It breaks because data is too big to fit your memory. `select *` grabs all the data in the table, you can't handle huge datasets in such a simple way.

Comment: @DavidG yes, I wan't to retreive data from the content of Xml Column

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov yes that's what happen, but I should have a solution, have you an idea ?

Comment: What is an "MO"?

Comment: I would suggest to shred/convert XML into a rectangular format on the SQL Server side.

Comment: That would be "MB", @Sarah .

Comment: basically this happens when it exceeds the limited memory which varys from devloper edition to entrprise edition SSMS is a 32-bit process. Therefore, it is limited to 2 GB of memory. SSMS imposes an artificial limit on how much text that can be displayed per database field in the results window. This limit is 64 KB in "Grid" mode and 8 KB in Text mode. If the result set is too large, the memory that is required to display the query results may surpass the 2 GB limit of the SSMS process. Therefore, a large result set can cause the error that is mentioned in the Symptoms section.

Comment: You should be using the `reader` to read one row at a time in a loop. Process each row as you go along. And **dispose your connection and reader objects** with `using`

Comment: @Charlieface even I read one column which contains xml data, there is the OutOfMemoryException, can I devided the content of one column ?

Comment: @Sarah reading it from the SqlDataReader you mean? Can you show us that code?

Comment: What is your intention? Do you need it all in a DataTable or can you process it row by row? Can you use XQuery `.value()` direct in SQL to get what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Solutions to your problem:

1. Either normalize your database such that rather than raw XML, appropriate relational model is stored. That is how SQL works in its essentials. Hopefully, that will solve your problem.
2. However, no matter how well your database is normalized, there are limits beyond which data simply does not fit available memory. If it is your case, you need to abandon tough `select *` way and reimplement it in fetch-next-batch size, i.e. repeatedly fetch batches of fixed predefined size, process them, mark as processed somewhere and go on.

Comment: Or work with it in `stream` fashion i.e. use the reader how is supposed to be: one row at a time

Comment: @Charlieface that’s exactly the second point.

Comment: Not really, it sounds more like you are saying to do lots of `select`s one after another, which can be dog slow. You should clarify. Another option is to pull out the relevant XML values with XQuery direct in the SQL

Answer (score 0):

Here is a conceptual example.
T-SQL shreds XML data type column into a rectangular format.
The c# side of the equation will not have any problem.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, product VARCHAR(20), xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (product, xmldata) VALUES
('vase',  N'<root>
    <r>red</r>
    <r>blue</r>
    <r>yellow</r>
</root>'),
('phone',  N'<root>
    <r>black</r>
    <r>white</r>
</root>');
-- DDL and sample data population, start

SELECT id, product
, c.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS color
FROM @tbl CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/root/r') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | product | color  |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 | vase    | red    |
|  1 | vase    | blue   |
|  1 | vase    | yellow |
|  2 | phone   | black  |
|  2 | phone   | white  |
+----+---------+--------+
```